# Where can I ask a question about advice for my job?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

For example, I want to know what would be the best way to approach someone that works for me about bad odor. What site can I use for this?

Comment: I just LOL'd. The answer would be: Start placing deodorants all around your PC: If he's not braindead, he'll begin suspecting something :). I'm too interested in such a site! (oh, no, I don't have co-workers with bad odor, but looks like an interesting site)

Comment: @DamienPirsy I've had complaints from other of the people that work for me also, I don't want it to get out of hand. Also, somebody voted to close? Isn't meta the right place to ask this question?

Comment: I don't know, but I respect the gravatar.  Is that 3S Ryu?!?  Even more respect.

Comment: Oh, so was that for real? I thought was just a funny example...Well, I know that approaching someone with such an issue is bad etiquette but...he must know, or to avoid losing one you'll lose all the others...Start with some "hinting" :). Don't know if there's a site, you can always propose one on [Area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @casperOne It is definitely Ryu, I'm not sure if the art is from 3rd Strike, but I loved the art and I have used it as an avatar in one place or another since I found it. Plus, there is no one cooler than Ryu.

Comment: @Marcelo If you're an SF fan (any version) or fighting game fan, and a technologist, and still play, we should talk.

Comment: @casperOne I'm a programmer and an avid gamer. Fighting games are among my favorite games, I am currently playing UMvC3 and a little SC5. How can we talk?

Comment: @Marcelo Check your invites, I've created a chat room which we can talk in.

Comment: @casperOne Didn't get one. Or maybe, I'm just being a noob, and can't seem to find it.

Comment: @Marcelo http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8448/chat-for-casperone-and-marcelo

Comment: Read an Emily Post book?

Answer (score 15):

There is an Area 51 proposal for [The Workplace](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/30887/the-workplace):

> Proposed Q&A site for members of the workforce navigating the professional setting.

Until then, you might be stuck.

**Edit:** [The Workplace](http://workplace.stackexchange.com) is now in public beta. Have at it.

Comment: well stuck using google.   There are tons of answers on google about this question.  I would do something to escape the odor :)

Comment: Bleh. Even without looking at that proposal, I know the example question would be off-topic there. How is anyone supposed to answer it objectively?

Comment: @Popular one of the up voted example questions there is about dealing with an irritating coworker. This question will be perfectly on topic for that site. The quality of that site, however, will be an entirely different matter...

Comment: Does it really matter if the example question is upvoted? Isn't this sort of question off-topic on any site per network policy? (Well, perhaps I should say "not constructive" instead of "off-topic," but the point is that such opinion polls are unwelcome, no? I once got into a mild argument with a mod of a site I was starting to participate in because he thought his community's desires trumped network policy, so I'd really like to know if I'm wrong on this one.)

Comment: @Popular I actually have no idea. A good question for Area 51 meta (or at least another MSO question).

Comment: @Pop: This is a common problem. People propose new sites because they want to be able to answer questions like this and they vehemently defend their right to do so. Then after a while, all of the regulars figure out that those questions are off-topic elsewhere on the network for a reason. The site just doesn't work, and they start retrenching, trying to change their policies and ban these types of questions. It's hard to rewrite history, and it's even harder to deter new users from coming there and asking this stuff because they *thought* it was the right place. Case study: Programmers.SE.

Comment: @Popular - you should ask that as a Meta question - I'm quite interested in hearing the answer, though I think Cody hinted at what the answer likely is

Comment: Oh, right, the question is here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124911/individual-community-preferences-vs-se-network-policy-who-wins Thanks for the reminder, @AdamRackis.

Comment: @Popular - saw it - got some great answers.  Glad to see the SE standards can be *bent* - the workplace proposal looks quite interesting, and I committed to it.

Answer (score 6):

I'd say nowhere. Drop by [chat](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/) & start talking with us!

Answer (score 5):

In the off chance someone hits this, there is currently a question on this [exact topic](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/621/2322) at the Workplace.