# Strange behaviour, community x moderation

Tags: discussion

Just voted to close a question on Stack Overflow in Portuguese, and saw this on the edit history:

https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/349/revisions

Which asks this (in portuguese):

> Are there good sites or books of introduction to programming in
>   Portuguese? What do you recommend as a first reading to an absolute
>   layman in programming?

It was closed and reopened twice. Didn't find any specifics on the reopening on the local meta, only some side discussion linked by @bigown (by the way, the original proponent of SO PT at Area 51, that seems to me is favorable to close the question too) at the end of the comments list.

What seems strange to me is, no one of the two mods involved give any feedback about the reopening on Meta. Probably it should happened, since it is against the community will (twice).

So, I asked this on our local meta, and posted this here just in case. Here is my local post (same question):

Sorry if I'm too "alarmed", but as our local SO is new, I really want the "upper staff" involved with our "fate".

Just FYI, I asked on our meta for an explanation.

> Our meta question: [Alguém pode me explicar o comportamento misterioso "comunidade" x "gerência"?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/837/comportamento-misterioso-comunidade-x-gerencia)

Comment: Seems that the Portugese mods see book recommendation questions differently than Stack Overflow does.

Comment: That question is pretty famous on Stack Overflow. In my personal opinion, every exchange should have one similar question to it as a book reference.

Comment: I'm not sure why they're reopening that - it's a pretty terrible question. But either way, this should stay on that site's Meta. This doesn't really have anything to do with us.

Comment: It seems we have just one mod that speaks portuguese, and he was against community opinion in other aspects too. Don't want to sound harsh, neither ungrateful. I'm just beginning to be worried.

Comment: @Travis: What question on Stack Overflow? Are you talking about the C++ book list question?  Because that question is one diamond in a sea  of turds, and we specifically disallow book recommendation questions otherwise.

Comment: @RobertHarvey - Actually I was referring to this one: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1711/1026459

Comment: @TravisJ You mean the one that's been locked and closed for quite some time now, specifically indicating that it's offtoipc?

Comment: @TravisJ: OK, two diamonds in a sea of turds.  I guess the Portugese mods figure they need at least one broken window, since we clearly have two.

Comment: @Servy - Yes, that one.

Comment: The revision history items aren't properly translated, someone get the torches and pitchforks!

Comment: That said, Theoretical Computer Science [has its own book recommendation question](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/3253/what-books-should-everyone-read) also.  It is *very carefully curated,* like the C++ book question is.

Comment: @TravisJ So you're linking to a closed book list and evidence that another book list should be reopened?  How does that work.  Your link is evidence that it should be closed.

Comment: @Servy - Contextually, I disagree. Why is it that no one considers new exchanges should follow a similar path of growth as the main exchanges that started all of this?

Comment: @TravisJ: Why would you want to learn the same painful lessons over and over?

Comment: @TravisJ "Why should we learn from our past mistakes and avoid the problems caused by them by preventing them from happening again?"  You *really* need that answered?

Comment: @TravisJ the community don't seem to want this. Only the mods involved.

Comment: Worth noting: the last mod that reopened that question is a Stack Exchange employee.

Comment: @RobertHarvey - Not all of them. But some do help. Such as being able to find relevant source material to reference.

Comment: @RobertHarvey the other doesn't seem to speak in portuguese, don't know how he is involved.

Comment: @Servy and Robert, sounds like you're deliberately straw-manning Travis' position. Can you not see the value in those questions existing on a StackExchange site and the traffic they bring, or are you being deliberately dogmatic?

Comment: @Servy - That? You *really* think that is my point?

Comment: @jball There is an explicit reason these questions are offtopic.  If they were worth the problems that they caused they would simply be ontopic questions.  *Significant* time and effort has resulted in the evaluation that they do not belong on these sites, and that we shouldn't allow them.  They're not disallowed for some arbitrary reason that none of us are even aware of, they're disallowed *because they hurt the site*.  I could go into detail as to why, but these argument have been re-hashed to death, so I'm not really interested in starting *yet another* one.

Comment: @Servy - You are overgeneralizing.

Comment: @jball: What straw man?  You've been around long enough to know how much strife was caused by book recommendation questions on Stack Overflow.  That's not a straw man, it's a real man.

Comment: @TravisJ How am I overgeneralizing?

Comment: @RobertHarvey Both current mods at that site are SE employees. And they're trying to push a looser approach on moderation (community moderation or not). However, we're really puzzled that they only say we need to be more open, and do not participate in most discussions about what the site rules should be. Personally, I was avoiding bringing this to MSO until I really understand WTF is going on there, but since it's been posted, I'm glad to hear more opinions.

Comment: @Robert the strawman that Travis is saying all bad early questions should be allowed on growing SE sites when he really said "every exchange should have one similar question to it as a book reference". You are generalizing his statement and criticizing the generalization, hardly helpful in an honest debate.

Comment: @Servy - You are referring to every instance of a book recommendation for every minute detail of a topic whereas I am specifically talking about one general place for book recommendations to be made. Once it has run its course then it can be locked and closed. But still, the post has a high amount of value to future readers on those small exchanges.

Comment: @Servy, see my above comment to Robert, with the followup question that I already posted, do you not see value in the traffic one or two of this kind of question can bring to a growing SE site?

Comment: @jball: Yeah, I don't see it.  You have to decide whether or not the benefits of having one or two book recommendations on your site is greater than the pain.  I don't see how that's overgeneralizing, and I don't see why you wouldn't consider a previous site's experiences when evaluating that decision.

Comment: @TravisJ Thousands of people have thought that they could create the next exceptional book recommendation question.  Virtually every single one of them created a steaming pile.  The community has determine, *repeatedly*, that they're better off without these questions.  Let a new site benefit from the *significant* problems caused by the fact that these questions weren't quashed sooner on SO.

Comment: @Servy - Thousands of people on SO. But not on Pets.SE, or any of the other smaller sites. Most of these exchanges will not reach the point where any problems aside from participation become *significant*.

Comment: @jball I see some value.  I also see all of the problems.  I consider them to be of net harm, which is consistent with the general community consensus.  SO is different because it had already generated the question when the decision was made not to allow these types of questions.  Had SO realized the problems that they cause sooner, it likely wouldn't even have any historically locked versions of them.

Comment: @TravisJ so, you think the whole majority of the community is wrong and the 2 mods, one foreigner, are right?

Comment: @Servy - It is also amusing you would profess to know anything of the side sites, as you haven't participated in any of them. What **experience** do you have to point to thousands of users on those exchanges?

Comment: @TravisJ: Oh, please.  ***It's Stack Overflow, in Portugese.***  You're not honestly asserting that it's a completely different site, are you?

Comment: @Bacco - I don't think this topic has been covered for smaller exchanges.

Comment: @RobertHarvey - No, I was referring to smaller exchanges.

Comment: @RobertHarvey - Do you know of any good programming books in Portugese?

Comment: @TravisJ The policy on avoiding recommendation questions is not SO policy, it's SE plicy.  In fact, it didn't even originate out of problems on SO, it originated out of problem on SF.  The entire network has come to the determination that these types of questions are not a fit for the Q/A style of the site design.  This is not strictly limited to very high traffic sites.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Actually, the very first post on our meta is titled ***This is NOT stackoverflow.com***. They really want something different out of that site, but are failing miserably in letting us know *what*.

Comment: @TravisJ: Ah, finally.  A **real** straw man.  FWIW I have no skin in this game.  Have your Portugese book recommendations if you want.  They don't affect me in any way on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @RobertHarvey - But since you bring it up... amazon lists only 40 books in Portugese on programming. There are 1500 on c# alone in English. Seems like a big difference to me.

Comment: @TravisJ That couldn't possibly be due to there actually being more English programming books in existence, could it?

Comment: @TravisJ well, so we just need to search for books in Amazon. No need for recommendations in SO.

Comment: @Bacco - Kind of like saying to read the manual instead of answering a question though isn't it? Amazon has a list, but not really a set of recommendations from professionals and enthusiasts.

Comment: @Servy - You aren't implying that there is a *difference* between the two are you?

Comment: @TravisJ When anyone in the entire world is capable of adding their book to the list, you're not exactly setting a high bar.

Comment: It seems Jaydles and Gabe decided run an experiment on SOpt. Community disagree. Aside note: Every programming book in portuguese is bad. Every site about programming in portuguesse is bad. SOpt should be the oasis for us.

Comment: @TravisJ I'm saying that Amazon is entirely adequate at the task of recommending programming books.  The reason it is providing less is because *there are less*.  That doesn't make it an inadequate recommendation mechanism, or SE a better one.

Comment: @Servy - Amazon lists books, but they don't recommend them. You can read some minute user feedback (if you are lucky for some of these low traffic areas). This is where the voting mechanism comes in to help set the bar and why SE in my opinion is better for that task.

Comment: @TravisJ And **past experience has demonstrated, over and over again, that such voting is not an effective tool for measuring the quality of book recommendations**, for any number of reasons, ranging from the fact that 1) popularity != quality 2) as books age, their value can decrease, but the votes remain 3) readers often don't look past the first few answers when voting 4) such lists usually have many books per answer, especially in the top answer 5) You don't have *experts* voting, you have anyone in the world with 15 rep voting

Comment: @Servy - Ok, fair enough. Those are good points.

Comment: 6) New books basically never get a chance to get anywhere near the top of the list, due to point #2, unless you start editing them into other answers, but if you do *that*, then you're now applying votes that were never cast to that book, to that book, making the votes effectively worthless.

Comment: @TravisJ: Amazon's recommendation engine has been a key part of the site since it started. Of course it recommends books.

Comment: @Wooble - They will offer a list of similar books, or they allow you to sort by popularity based on user ratings. However, with no ratings Amazon can struggle. For example on the topic of Portuguese programming books, of which almost none are rated, Amazon cannot tell you one way or the other about them, and the "featured recommendations" is empty. Amazon is awesome, but their system is also based on a very similar metric SE would use.

Answer (score 10):

First off: this is something that y'all need to work out among yourselves. There's an ongoing discussion regarding the nature of that question here: [Como podemos lidar com as "listas"?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/819/como-podemos-lidar-com-as-listas) and the question itself should *probably* be locked until that concludes. The folks participating in that discussion - Gabe, bfavaretto, bigown, Bacco, Sergio and others have all raised some valid points, but reading through the (machine-translated) discussion thus far I'm not seeing a clear *solution*. So to address your point: there's no clear documentation for why it should be closed/reopened because that discussion is still in progress.

Beyond that... I think you're asking *why* this question would become a focal point for such discussion in the first place. I've been working with Gabe on structuring this discussion, and I'd prefer it stayed on PT.SO, but since you brought it up here I'll try to explain some of the background...

### Individual Stack Exchange sites vs. network standards

PT.SO is *not* Stack Overflow. There's a decent amount of overlap between the membership on both sites right now, but I don't expect this to be true for very long. Because of this, [it isn't enough to just transplant the standards and practices currently in effect on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124911/individual-community-preferences-vs-se-network-policy-who-wins/124915#124915):

> If the community doesn't establish their own standards *and* buy into ours, they won't enforce any of them. [As Robert notes, we provide plenty of guidance](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124911/individual-community-preferences-vs-se-network-policy-who-wins/124915#124915), but each community must **make it their own** - and during that process, each site develops a bit of local flavor. Some sites are extremely strict as to form and topic, others are considerably more flexible. *And that's ok...*

Learning from history is a big part of building a new Stack Exchange community. But this must follow the form of learning from past *problems* and implementing solutions that work for each individual site: folks who fail to keep this in mind and try to shut down problematic practices with a blunt, "this violates Stack Exchange rules" find themselves perpetually embroiled in heated and unproductive discussions.

#### Monkeys and ladders and programmers

There's an old story about [monkeys and a ladder](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/6828/was-the-experiment-with-five-monkeys-a-ladder-a-banana-and-a-water-spray-condu) that's supposed to demonstrate how rules can be passed on long past the point where anyone remembers why they were put into place...

...Turns out, it's probably bunk. Monkeys don't work that way. And neither do programmers. If there's a tasty banana or useful topic to be had, a few old primates yelling about *dire consequences* are going to be ignored. **You have to be able to explain *why* something is a bad idea** - and if at all possible, offer an alternative solution.

Ideally, this can be accomplished without having to make the same mistakes and repeat the same bitter arguments on *every* new site. But the only way that'll happen is by conducting informed discussions focused on specific problems - sweeping them under the rug doesn't work.

### Lists

...Which brings us to the topic at hand. Let's face it: that question sucks right now. You don't need years of history on Stack Exchange to tell you that it's not a particularly good reference. But... It *does* reflect a real need. There's a reason lists of books were popular on Stack Overflow for *years* and still feature prominently in several wikis (either tag wikis or Community Wiki questions): new programmers who are conscientious enough to actually want to do some self-study *desperately* want a short list of expertly-chosen books that'll help them do so. And it shouldn't surprise anyone that the Portuguese community is under-served in this regard as well... [Bigown attests to this frustration](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/220791/strange-behaviour-community-x-moderation#comment716116_220791):

> Aside note: Every programming book in portuguese is bad. Every site about programming in portuguesse is bad. SOpt should be the oasis for us.

If the demand for these references was so great on Stack Overflow (where the English-speaking audience has a wealth of existing book lists, Amazon reviews, etc.) that it took us years to be rid of it, imagine how hungry the audience on PT.SO will be! This strikes me as a very real need, and one that will be very difficult to just ignore.

So then, what can be done? If this format for questions is known to work poorly but the audience is clamoring for them anyway, how do we resolve this tension?

Well, that's the point of [the discussion that Gabe raised the other day](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/819/como-podemos-lidar-com-as-listas): to get folks involved in finding a way of serving those with a need without hurting the site. I'll note that this is hardly the first time a Stack Exchange site has faced this question: communities as diverse as RaspberryPi and English Language Learners have both found themselves faced with a large, inexperienced audience in desperate need of learning resources, and have found ways to step up to the challenge.

It's not an easy problem to solve, but I have faith that the good folks on PT.SO are up to the challenge.

Comment: **"but each community must make it their own"**. This is my sole point. The mods are doing their own, as the community closed the question. The reopening could be community driven after the discussion, if they could make their point and convince people to change their minds. Instead, it was forced down the throat.

Comment: Also: I thought that "moderator powers" should arise when community fails. Is this the case?

Comment: As I said above, the question probably should have been *locked* while under discussion - I'm not entirely sure why it was *reopened* instead; I'll find out once I'm off the phone.

Comment: Anyway thanks regarding the faith in our community and interest on the problem. Consider my almost-overreaction as an early ringing bell only.

Comment: +1 for `Monkeys and Ladders` - sometimes the best teaching tool is to let the younger monkeys climb the ladder and find out what happens. (and in this case it's not like all the older monkeys have to get hit with the fire hose: How many of us speak Portuguese?)

Comment: @Bacco, I reopened the question because we, *really* want to ensure that we start from a place where we allow most questions that we believe can help programmers, and then *vigilantly* watch for which ones become a problem or threat to the site.  We started from that approach and laid it out in the initial meta post that explicitly talked about  needed to allow more while we see how the community evolves.  We are extremely committed to this site's success, which is why we believe so strongly that we should allow as much help as we can, and then address the actual problems as they arise.

Comment: I am concerned that if PT.SO allows something, then it will make it more likely that people who use both PT.SO and SO will do the same on SO.     As the name of the two sites are so close to each other, I think both sites should have the same policies, or the name of PT.SO should be changed.

Comment: There are going to be differences, @Ian. That's unavoidable - the *people* are different. They should be subtle, but keep in mind that standards vary between different communities *within Stack Overflow* so you can expect a slightly exaggerated reflection of this on a different site in a different language.