# Is asking for guidance a "request for materials"?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, off-topic

Why are questions asking about guidance closed as off-topic requests for materials? Would it not be beneficial to the community to allow the more experienced users to pour their knowledge on the newer ones? By guidance I mean the initial chapters on some subject to point beginners in the right direction (not technologies, but rather timeless principles).

Comment: “why are such requests for materials off-topic?” - They are unhelpful to the rest of the community. An answer to such a request would involve the individual writing the answer to find the documentation, and if the author of the answer could find that documentation, it begs the question why the author of the question couldn’t find it. To put it simply a repository of links to hundreds of documentation websites isn’t helpful.

Comment: Welcome to the global meta site for the Stack Exchange network! As it currently stands, this question is not a good fit for this network meta site, as this is only about one specific site in our network, Unix & Linux. Do note that each site on our network has its own separate meta site, which in this case is [Unix & Linux Meta](//unix.meta.stackexchange.com/). If you want to learn more about that site's specific policy, I'd recommend you ask there instead of here.

Comment: That said, there's a [pretty good post here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/158809/377214) that explains why most sites on our network don't accept requests for recommendations in general. Sadly, the best we can provide here on this global meta site is general advice for most sites; if you want more info on a specific site's policy, please go and ask on that site's own meta.

Comment: Thanks to everyone who answered and commented. I got mislead to this meta from the link I got in the help popup when closing the question.

Comment: I also thought this affected all communities: the kind of answer I was expecting was something like "first learn X, then learn Y, and with that then you can move on to Z", which would be good for any topic in any stack exchange community from linux to algebra, from games to history.

Comment: The key word in your question seems to be syllabus, which means: "an outline of the subjects in a course of study or teaching.". Asking about the syllabus on one site about education can be off-topic: https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1329/103165 though there's another site where self-learning questions can be asked:  https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/self-learning (but most of those questions are closed).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why was my "shopping list" question closed?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158809/why-was-my-shopping-list-question-closed)

Comment: You missed that [we hate fun](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/01/04/stack-overflow-where-we-hate-fun/). The only outlets are [tag burnination requests](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/416466/page-numberings-days-are-numbered) (only in titles) and the occasional [meme reference](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19514#19514).

Comment: Maybe the new version of the question makes my point clearer :)

Comment: While no longer site-specific, it is still a duplicate of [Why was my "shopping list" question closed?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/158809/377214): that question explains well why most sites don't accept recommendation requests. Not sure why the reviewers said that the original close reason wasn't resolved; if I were reviewing, I would have either reviewed that the duplicate reason applies or voted to reopen and re-close as a duplicate.

Comment: I still disagree. In my opinion, one thing would be to ask for a list of the best IDEs to develop code, and another would be to ask what the principles of programming are. This applies to all subjects: asking what are the basics of statistics for data science against asking for the best framework for XYZ. I do agree that a few days of Googling and buying books will serve the purpose of education, I just wanted to know if such educational questions were fit for stack exchange communities.

Comment: With all due respect, I'm starting to feel that you're more interested in finding reasons to close the question rather than understanding what I'm saying. So, if you'll be so kind to flag the question I'll delete it this time. Don't get me wrong, I don't intend to be disrespectful. I just feel like this has turned from educational to a waste of time to all potential readers and writers.

Answer (score 7):

If you are seeking learning material or any other recommendations, my advice is to not ask for them directly.  I think you will find that if you:

- do your research first,
- say what you are looking for,
- say what you have looked at,
- say what your best candidate is, and
- describe the single main concern you have with proceeding to use that, and
- ask about that specifically

then you will most likely receive answers that either alleviate that concern, or most professionals, recognizing someone on the "wrong track", will say "you may want to try XXX instead because it meets that requirement in this way".

As soon as you outright ask for a recommendation you are asking for the community to put together a list of options for you to choose one from i.e. most answers will be wasted effort by our volunteers.

One final bit of advice by @Shog9 in [Individual community preferences vs. SE network policy: who wins?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124911/individual-community-preferences-vs-se-network-policy-who-wins)

> - Want a bunch of lists of recommendations? Be warned that they’ve led to the death of at least one site, and bitter arguments on many
>   more. If you're trying to attract experts, then focus on questions
>   that require some sort of expertise to answer.

Comment: Thanks @PolyGeo. So, to make sure I got the point, if I know nothing about a subject Stack Exchange communities is not the place to go "Hey! Where should I start studying about this subject?". Right?

Comment: @perepm no one knows nothing about a subject they are interested in for very long so first step could be to Google it

Answer (score 2):

Well, we generally want our answers to be self-contained - and if a website is down, or a book not available, the knowledge is lost. It’s in a sense a synthesis of a few things we picked up over the years

- Our policy on [link-only answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer)
- the eventual interpretation of [our shopping recommendations rule](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/11/23/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/)

The Q&A format also works better with specific issues - with people citing their sources and giving a solution that stands on its own

Kali Linux's also a bit of a sore point on U&L - [see this](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5360/27961) and related

There's a space between "I want a fish" and "I need to find a book on how to make a fishing rod from scratch" - "What bait should I use to catch a giant catfish?" or "My line keeps breaking, what I am doing wrong" - and that's where we're best at.

Basically, it’s just not what *we're* good at, as a platform, and more free-form formats like forums or [Reddit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reddit) might work better for open ended questions like that.

Comment: Thank you very much. The last paragraph of the shopping recommendations rule kind of says what I'm saying, isn't it? "If I had to summarize our network in a single word, that word is “learning”. People come to our sites to learn about topics they are passionate about. As the old Chinese proverb goes, “Give a man a fish and you feed him for a day. Teach a man to fish and you feed him for a lifetime.” Every question and answer ultimately should be about teaching and learning — yes, even the shopping ones."